# Oraginizing django urlpatterns for APIs

Tags: python, django

I would like to use an api version index for all my API endpoints (`api/v1/`). Currently I'm achieving it by structuring my urlpatterns like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/units/', include('units.api.urls')),
    path('api/v1/accounts/', include('accounts.api.urls')),
]
```

Is there a way to organize this more elegantly? Ideally I would like it to look something like this:

```
apipatterns = [
    'units/', include('units.api.urls'),
    'accounts/', include('accounts.api.urls')
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(apipatterns)),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "ideal" urlpatterns are almost correct. Here is the corrected variant:

```
apipatterns = [
     path('units/', include('units.api.urls')),
     path('accounts/', include('accounts.api.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(apipatterns)),
]
```

Here is a similar example in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `path` and `include` for [Including other URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

In you case you can Try:

```
apipatterns = [
    path('units/', include('units.api.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.api.urls'))
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(apipatterns)),
]
```

So the route `api/v1/units/` will be handled by `'units.api.urls'`, and `api/v1/accounts/` will be handled by `'accounts.api.urls'`

I hope this will help.